# How to get data in parenthesis and make new row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Could you please advise on how to get data in between parentheses and make a new row in data frame pandas

The conditions are:

### Case1: If row's first letter starts with lower case and has parenthesis
we don't need to check data inside parenthesis we need to check only the row is starting with small case or not

- Entry 1: Drug_Name = Col 1, Tier = Col 2, Restriction = Col 3.
- Entry 2: Drug_Name = Info in parenthesis in col 1, Tier = Col 2, Restriction = Col 3.

### Case 2:

- Otherwise Drug_Name = Col 1, Tier = Col 2, Restriction= Col 3

Input:
sample input file http://www.filedropper.com/input_2

expected output: http://www.filedropper.com/output_2

Comment: If you know regular expressions, you can use pd.Series.str.extract.

Answer (score 2):

To extract the value you can use `str.extractall`. If you want all values, you can create a copy of the values and then append it back:

```
df2 =df.copy()
df2['Drug Name'] = df['Drug Name'].str.extractall(r'[a-z]?.*?\((.+)\).*',flags=re.MULTILINE).reset_index()[0]
df2 = df2.dropna() # df2 contains only values inside parantheses
pd.concat([df,df2])
```

Comment: It's not extracting all values, some rows has double brackets like
"calcium carbonate (antacid) chew tab 400 mg (Childrens Pepto)"
"calcium carbonate (antacid) chew tab 500 mg (Calcium Antacid)"
"calcium carbonate (antacid) chew tab 750 mg(Cvs Smooth Antacid Extra)"
"calcium carbonate (antacid) chew tab 1000 mg (Gnp Antacid Ultra Strengt)"
only first bracketed data extracting second one is not extracting

Comment: @ashok I thought your example was talking about extracting only the values in lower case? Could you tell me if that is not the case? If you would like to match also the second values remove the `[a-z] ` and use `extractall` instead of extract. Let me know if you still have a problem.

Comment: I need to check every row first character, if it is in lowercase and has parenthesis(doesn't matter what ever the data inside parenthesis and no need to check the case also in side parenthesis ), on this condition we need to extract all parenthesis data and rest will remains the same please check my input and out put you get to know

Comment: Not correct please check my expected output screenshot in "Aalcium carbonate (antacid) chew tab 400 mg\n(Childrens Pepto)" we have data in two parenthesis we should get Tier and restriction same for both after extraction because they are from same cell but in our case it was missing for all two parenthesis 
please check my input and expected output once

Comment: Also it's not extracting all bracketed values Maoxis not extracted and base equiv is not extracted

Comment: @ashok I tried this on a sample of your dataframe and it works very well for me. Perhaps there are certain strings that are special cases in your dataframe. If you want, you can supply a sample of your dataframe (not a screenshot) and show the output and the expected output. I would be glad to change the regex to match your case.

Comment: please go through this file  which contains two sheets Input and Output http://www.filedropper.com/data_9

Comment: @ashok I'm sorry but I will not go through the file like that. You need to get a small sample showing the expected behaviour and post it in the original question so that other who read your question in the future can understand the problem better.

Comment: I have updated it in the question it self, that was the sample data files I just placed the same data from screen shots to files